# Why do we need the index in the epsilon definition of a convergent sequence?

Tags: real-analysis

I am taking a real analysis class and we just learned the definition of convergent sequences. While I understand what the definition is doing. I do not *really* understand the point of the index.

The definition as I understand it is:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \; \;  \exists N:n\geq N \Rightarrow |S_{n} -S|<\epsilon $

What is the point of the index $N$?

How is the above definition any different than:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \; \;  \exists n\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow|S_{n} -S|<\epsilon $

Or some other formulation that does not include the index?

Comment: You mean $n \ge N$ in the definition. Your proposed modification is much weaker than the desired condition: we want to know that $S_n$ eventually gets within $\epsilon$ of $S$ and *stays there* whereas your condition just says that $S_n$ eventually gets within $\epsilon$ of $S$ but then is free to wander off later.

Comment: $\forall \epsilon \;  \exists n\in\mathbb{R} \Rightarrow|S_{n} -S|<\epsilon$ is not even a coherent statement, because there's no proposition on the left side of the $\Rightarrow$. In words, what are you proposing as an alternative definition?

Comment: I made a type and said $n<N$ I have corrected it in my question.

Comment: @DavidK: Let's assume OP is using $\Rightarrow$ to mean "such that." :-D OP, strictly speaking, you've written, in plain English, "For all positive $\varepsilon$, if there exists a real $n$, then $S_n$ differs from $S$ by at most $\varepsilon$." Technically, this is meaningless; in this case, it can be inferred what you mean, but in more complicated expressions, it could be very difficult to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed alternative (or at least an attempt at interpreting it):

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists n \in \mathbb{N} : |S_n - S| < \epsilon$

Reads as:

> For every positive value $\epsilon$, there is a natural number $n$ such that $S_n$ is within $\epsilon$ of $S$.

But that just means that we can find *one* element of the sequence that is arbitrarily close to $S$. But if we take, for example, the sequence $1, 0, 0, 0, 0, \ldots$, then $a_1 = 1$ so if we set $S = 1$ and $n = 1$ then we get $|S_1 - S| = 0 < \epsilon$ for every real epsilon, which satisfies the above requirement. But clearly we want a definition of limit that satisfies $\lim a_n = 0$ for this sequence, so that can't be right.

The other definition you gave is the stronger condition we need - for any $\epsilon$, we can find a point in the sequence where *every* element after that point is within $\epsilon$ of the limit value.

Comment: Thank you, this helped to clarify my confusion. So, in your example of $1,0,0,0...$ and the correct definition of convergence we would say something like $N=1$ and then for the sequence to converge every $n\geq N$ would have to satisfy $|S_{n}-S|<\epsilon$?

Comment: Assuming your sequence starts with $S_0$, then yes picking $N = 2$ independent of $\epsilon$ works here. Generally though $N$ will depend on $\epsilon$.